# Reset in css without overwrite and without !important

Tags: html, css

**HTML:**

```
<div id="div_id"><div class="div_class"><p>test</p> </div>
    <div class="two"> <p>asd</p></div>    
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#div_id p {
  color:red;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
}

.two p {
  // here reset all
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/Wwh2C/1/

`<p>asd</p>` looks the same. How can I reset all in `.two p`? I must repeat `color`, `background-color` and `width`? I would like reset all without overwrite and without use of `!important`.

Comment: what is your question here? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/DrVbY/)

for some reason it didn't like the leaving off of the #div_id in the css declaration, but adding it worked.

```
#div_id p {
  color:red;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
}

#div_id .two p {
  color:inherit;
  background-color: inherit;
  width:auto;
}
```

Comment: The reason it didn't work when you left off `#div_id` is because an ID has a higher specificity value than a class. So `#div_id p` wins out over `.two p`. But by adding the id as well as the class meant that `#div_id .two p` had a higher specificity value than just `#div_id p`.

Comment: @tw16 thanks for clarifying that!  I'm glad to have a reason to the anomaly XD

Answer (score 1):

`#div_id p` is selecting `any p that appears below #div_id` and `.two p` is selecting `any p that appears below .two`.  Make the first rule:

`#div_id > div > p`

to specificaly target the first `p` only.  That way, you won't need to reset anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm why not : (?)

```
#div_id .div_class p{
  color:red;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
}

#div_id .two p{
/*whatever you like, not concerned by previous statement*/
}
```